# Json output to exclude field name, but include its class fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have 2 classes, one includes the other

```
class TestClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private AnotherClass another
}

class AnotherClass {
   private String details
}
```

I would like json output for TestClass to only include AnotherClass's field directly and not show the field another:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "details": "test details"
}
```

I found the solution.Use @JsonUnwrapped on field another.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), you can use the [JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation:

```
class TestClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private AnotherClass another
}

class AnotherClass {
   private String details
}
```